# Magical Record crashing with this message

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Default Context is nil! Did you forget to initialize the Core Data Stack?

```
+ (void)saveSplashImageData:(NSString*)data {
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [SplashImage MR_truncateAllInContext:localContext];
    SplashImage *splashImage = [SplashImage MR_createInContext:localContext];
    splashImage.imageData = data;
    [localContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}

+ (SplashImage*)loadSplashImage {
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    SplashImage *splashImage  = [SplashImage  MR_findFirstInContext:localContext];
    if (splashImage) {
        NSLog(@"Test");
    }
    return splashImage;
}
```

Anyone with any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you forget to initialize the Core Data Stack?

Comment: Thanks. I figured how to initialise the Core Data Stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this in the AppDelegate.m did the trick.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"Flexi.sqlite"];
    return YES;
}
```